# Opening search results with Vim ONLY if they exist

Tags: vim, grep, gvim, xargs, ack

:) In my never-ending effort to get lazier, I am looking for a way to improve my "Open Grep/Ack-results in Vim"-snippet. What I'm currently using to open found files is:

```
vim $(ack -il "pattern")
```

Using it is a blaze, but it involves one catch - Vim will open regardless if the number of files found is 0 (in other words, Vim opens with nothing loaded into the buffer). Is there any elegant way to avoid this completely insignificant problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
files=$(ack -il "pattern") && vim $files
```

(Tested with `grep` since I don't have `ack`.) Note that that won't work if `ack` returns files with spaces in their names.

Comment: Both solutions provided are fine options, setting this one as the accepted one as it is shorter :) Thanks both!

Answer (score 4):

How about immediately quitting Vim when no arguments have been passed:

```
vim -c 'if !argc()|quit|endif' $(ack -il "pattern")
```